# Blank page with recyclerview within mvvm-model

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, mvvm, android-recyclerview

I am kind of new and ran into an issue where I get an error instead of a recyclerview,

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.vernaljobs/com.example.vernaljobs.NoteMain}: kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
```

My recyclerview is not showing, trying to insert one through an 'add button' does not give anything either.

```
class NoteMain : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var noteViewModel: NoteViewModel? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_note_main)
        val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recycler_view)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
        val adapter = NoteAdapter()
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter

        noteViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(NoteViewModel(application)::class.java)
       error-> noteViewModel!!.getAllNotes()!!.observe(this,
            Observer {notes -> adapter.setNotes(notes) })
    }
}
```

And my database file, where I listed 3 elements I want to retrieve,

```
@Database(entities = [Note::class], version = 1)
abstract class NoteDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun noteDao(): NoteDao

    class PopulateDbAsyncTask(db: NoteDatabase) : AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        private val noteDao: NoteDao = db.noteDao()

        override fun doInBackground(vararg voids: Void): Void? {
            noteDao.insert(Note("Title 1", "Description 1", 1))
            noteDao.insert(Note("Title 2", "Description 2", 2))
            noteDao.insert(Note("Title 3", "Description 3", 3))
            return null
        }
    }


    companion object {

        private lateinit var instance: NoteDatabase

        @Synchronized
        fun getInstance(context: Context): NoteDatabase {
            return instance
        }

        private val roomCallback = object : RoomDatabase.Callback() {
            override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                super.onCreate(db)
                PopulateDbAsyncTask(instance).execute()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Adapter class

class NoteAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter() {
    private var notes: List = ArrayList()

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): NoteHolder {
    val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.note_item, parent, false)
    return NoteHolder(itemView)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(@NonNull holder: NoteHolder, position: Int) {
    val currentNote = notes[position]
    holder.textViewTitle.text = currentNote.title
    holder.textViewDescription.text = currentNote.description
    holder.textViewPriority.text = currentNote.priority.toString()
}

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return notes.size
}

fun setNotes(notes: List<Note>) {
    this.notes = notes
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}

 inner class NoteHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    val textViewTitle: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_title)
    val textViewDescription: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_description)
    val textViewPriority: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_priority)
}
```

}

ViewModel

class NoteViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

```
    private var repository: NoteRepository?= null
    private var allNotes: LiveData<List<Note>>? = null

fun insert(note: Note) {
    repository?.insert(note)
}

fun update(note: Note) {
    repository?.update(note)
}

fun delete(note: Note) {
    repository?.delete(note)
}

fun deleteAllNotes() {
    repository?.deleteAllNotes()
}

fun getAllNotes(): LiveData<List<Note>>? {
    return allNotes
}
```

}

Repository

```
private val noteDao: NoteDao? = null
private val allNotes: LiveData<List<Note>>? = null

fun NoteRepository(application: Application) {
    val database = NoteDatabase.getInstance(application)
    val noteDao = database.noteDao()
    val allNotes = noteDao.allNotes
}

fun insert(note: com.example.vernaljobs.Note) {
    if (noteDao != null) {
        InsertNoteAsyncTask(noteDao).execute(note)
    }
}

fun update(note: com.example.vernaljobs.Note) {
    if (noteDao != null) {
        UpdateNoteAsyncTask(noteDao).execute(note)
    }
}

fun delete(note: com.example.vernaljobs.Note) {
    if (noteDao != null) {
        DeleteNoteAsyncTask(noteDao).execute(note)
    }
}

fun deleteAllNotes() {
    if (noteDao != null) {
        DeleteAllNotesAsyncTask(noteDao).execute()
    }
}

fun getAllNotes(): LiveData<List<Note>>? {
    return allNotes
}

private class InsertNoteAsyncTask(private val noteDao: NoteDao) :
    AsyncTask<com.example.vernaljobs.Note, Void, Void>() {

    override fun doInBackground(vararg notes: com.example.vernaljobs.Note): Void? {
        noteDao.insert(notes[0])
        return null
    }
}

private class UpdateNoteAsyncTask(private val noteDao: NoteDao) :
    AsyncTask<com.example.vernaljobs.Note, Void, Void>() {

    override fun doInBackground(vararg notes: com.example.vernaljobs.Note): Void? {
        noteDao.update(notes[0])
        return null
    }
}

private class DeleteNoteAsyncTask(private val noteDao: NoteDao) :
    AsyncTask<com.example.vernaljobs.Note, Void, Void>() {

    override fun doInBackground(vararg notes: com.example.vernaljobs.Note): Void? {
        noteDao.delete(notes[0])
        return null
    }
}

private class DeleteAllNotesAsyncTask(private val noteDao: NoteDao) :
    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

    override fun doInBackground(vararg voids: Void): Void? {
        noteDao.deleteAllNotes()
        return null
    }
}
```

}

Comment: can you explicitly point at the error line, we don't see line numbers here

Comment: where is the getAllNotes method?
Either the ViewModel or that method are returning null.

Comment: Post code of your viewmodel

Comment: ok, updated, thx for trying to help

Comment: @WoutStack, for example, your `ViewModel` has `getAllNotes()` method which returns a `LiveData` which is `null` and I don't see any initialization of it/.